# Mysterious '...' at end of my strings, although it doesn't seem to be a char?

Tags: javascript, string, unit-testing, jasmine

I am running Unit tests on my JavaScript, however, the following test is failing:

```
it('should pass tags without code clean through', function () {
    //some logic
    expect(processed_content).toBe(data);
});
```

however, I am getting the error shown below. Both strings seem to be identical, and when copy and pasted into an [Online Diff Checker](https://www.diffchecker.com/) it reports they are identical.

```
1) Test Migrator should pass tags without code clean through
1.1) Expected '---
title: Location
description: How to work with geographical location data.
---
To import the module in your code use:
{% nativescript %}
JavaScript
var geolocation = require("nativescript-geolocation");

' to be '---
title: Location
description: How to work with geographical location data.
---
To import the module in your code use:
{% nativescript %}
JavaScript
var geolocation = require("nativescript-geolocation");

'.
```

However, when I tried comparing `processed_content.split('')` and `data.split('')` and this is what I got:

[image]

So you can see there is a difference in how the end of file is being dealt with during my processing, which in this use case should just read a file and write it straight back. So Why is there a `...` at the end of my original file and only a `..` at the end of the processed version? More to the point, how can I ignore this quirk in my test, as it doesn't seem to be a char, as it isn't inside inverted commas?

NB: I have tried `processed_content.split('').slice(0, processed_content.length - 1)` but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

## Update:

Thanks for the suggestion to try `.trim()` unfortunately that doesn't help, if I call `processed_content.trim().split('')`, I still get the `...` and `..` (although that function does kill the commas I was seeing).

Still anymore ideas would be much appreciated as this is still biting me ...

Comment: Try trimming both the strings before comparing.

Comment: I don't know if it's a typing mistake but in the code you provided I don't see the two results are equal (exactly at the description part). The first one: "description: How to work with geographical location data." And the second one: "description: How to work with geographical location data in NativeScript.".

Comment: @bcap yes that's a typing error, I'll fix the question. The original results are the same though)

Comment: @Tushar thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately, that doesn't work - see my updated question. It does remove the commas though!